# C++ Using proper child-class pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism, type-deduction

basically, I want to implement document type converter. I've designed pretty straight-forward solution:

1. `DocTypeParser : Parser` will converts file into tree structure of nodes, representing different elements (headers, lists, bold texts, ...)
2. `DocTypePrinter : Printer` will deconstruct that tree back into text file

So far so good, but I came across nasty problem - The connection between tree nodes is estabilished through `std::vector<Node *>` and I am not sure how to determine what child class is being processed.

**My demo code:**

```
class Node
{
  public:
    Node()
    {
    }
    ~Node()
    {
        for (auto it : Leaf)
            delete it;
    }

    Node &Add(Node *leaf)
    {
        Leaf.push_back(leaf);
        return *this;
    }

    std::vector<Node *> Leaf;
};

class NodeA : public Node
{
  public:
    NodeA() : Node()
    {
    }
};

class Printer
{
  public:
    Printer() = default;
    std::string Print(Node &n)
    {
        int i = 0, k = n.Leaf.size();
        std::string res = "<n>";
        for (; i < k; ++i)
            res += Print(*(n.Leaf[i]));
        res += "</n>";
        return res;
    }
    std::string Print(NodeA &n)
    {
        int i = 0, k = n.Leaf.size();
        std::string res = "<A>";
        for (; i < k; ++i)
            res += Print(*(n.Leaf[i]));
        res += "</A>";
        return res;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    NodeA tree;
    tree.Add(new NodeA).Add(new NodeA);

    Printer p;
    std::cout << p.Print(tree) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

*Desired result:* `<A><A></A><A></A></A>`

*Actual result:* `<A><n></n><n></n></A>`

I pretty much understand what is the problem (vector stores `Node` pointers, not `NodeChild` pointers), but not that sure how to overcome that. `dynamic_cast` seems to be not-the-solution-at-all.

So finally **question** - is there cure for me or am I longing for the wrong design altogether?

Comment: What type of file do you want to parse? XML?

Comment: Markdown, dokuwiki and maybe texy (its school project btw).

Comment: You'll want to look into implementing a Visitor Pattern

Comment: Okay, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used type erasure wrongly. Your nodes accessed by `Node*` , so `*(n.Leaf[i])` expression returns type `Node`, not `NodeA`.

What you do resembles visitor pattern, to recognize which class is which you have to use a virtual method in Node class and override it in NodeA, calling it with  dispatcher as argument (classic visitor) or calling it from dispatcher  you can recognize which instance is which.

In first case node would call the Print method and pass it `*this`.

This is minimal rework of your code, but I think, it needs honing\optimizing. Depends on what your actual task is, vistor might be a little too excessive.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
class Node;
class NodeA;

class AbstractPrinter 
{
public:
    virtual std::string Print(Node &n) =0;
    virtual std::string Print(NodeA &n) =0;
};

class Node
{
  public:
    Node()
    {
    }
    virtual ~Node()
    {
        for (auto it : Leaf)
            delete it;
    }

    Node &Add(Node *leaf)
    {
        Leaf.push_back(leaf);
        return *this;
    }

    virtual std::string  Print(AbstractPrinter& p)
    {
        return p.Print(*this);
    }

    std::vector<Node *> Leaf;
};

class NodeA : public Node
{
  public:
    NodeA() : Node()
    {
    }

    // if not override this, it would use Node
    virtual std::string  Print(AbstractPrinter& p) override
    {
        return p.Print(*this);
    }
};

class Printer : public AbstractPrinter
{
  public:
    Printer() = default;
    std::string Print(Node &n)
    {
        int i = 0, k = n.Leaf.size();
        std::string res = "<n>";
        for (; i < k; ++i)
            res += n.Leaf[i]->Print(*this);
        res += "</n>";
        return res;
    }
    std::string Print(NodeA &n)
    {
        int i = 0, k = n.Leaf.size();
        std::string res = "<A>";
        for (; i < k; ++i)
            res +=  n.Leaf[i]->Print(*this);
        res += "</A>";
        return res;
    }
};
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    NodeA tree;
    tree.Add(new NodeA).Add(new NodeA);

    Printer p;
    std::cout << tree.Print(p) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Neat, that should do it I see! Thank you and @AndyG as well as he pointed that out too.

Comment: @KryštofŠádek I added working edit of your code, but I think, the architecture need rework, too many calls forth and back with this architecture. And you can employ templates there.

Comment: I made somewhat working implementation and it is working pretty well. I agree that calling methods back and forth isn't exactly optimal (not to mention copying ever-growing string as return value all over the place), but it separates proccessing into those three categories (parser, tree, printer) which makes format support expansion relatively simple. Plus polymorphism is required in this case and as I am not that much familiar with it, I am really glad I figured at least some way how to utilize it.

Comment: @KryštofŠádek the copy thing can be fixed, provided that compiler aggressively helps in that (copy elision, move semantics)  if you organize code properly. Pretty much when you tried to store pointers to `NodeA` as `Node*` WAS attempt to use polymorphism: its feature *subtyping*.  Without dispatcher polymorphism use would look like a call to virtual a method. Dispatcher allows to separate subsystems, e.g. you can replace `Printer` with `FilePrinter` derived from same abstract class.